# How to manage reluctant or negligent colleagues to be interested about meetings, administration, or Kanban introduction?

Tags: team-management, project-team, kanban, meetings

The beginning of the next year we would like to optimize our system (we working in the recruitment industry, the market is changing in every minutes). With my compeer we worked out a plan and the founders have accepted it. Moreover, we got budget and gave plenty of rope.

Our goal is to study our process and optimize it, and share the knowledge around the system. However, we have some negligent guys who do not really believe in our work, they are always late, don't do administrative topics, and slight our view.

What are the best practices to make this change happen and help these colleagues to part of our initiative?

Comment: First of all I am the original questioner but made two accounts by accident:) So, @Zsolt thank you for your work about editing my question:) CodeGnome we are a really fresh start-up and haven't got any transparent culture regarding the workplace and the flow also so I can't compare the recent one with the former one:( Zsolt they haven't got any remarkable counter argument...just saying "we don't like to regulate you...we are a start-up and feel free to do anything and be productive", I can't describe this type of habit but these guys sometimes non-committal with general 'rules' but they are de

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, first I would figure out what is their counter argument against the change because we are talking about change here. Second, what can I do in order to make it easier for them unless we are talking about 2 persons out of 100. Finally, if the rest of the organisation is fine with the new way of working and they have only personal concerns such as *"I don't like it"*, I would simply go forward and do it.

The most common counter arguments are actually quite valid. They don't know what going to happen them, their carriers, their goals, their influence (this is quite interesting actually), and their social capital inside the company (the value of their network). Try to address these and see what is going to happen.

Comment: +1 for _"figure out what is their counter argument"_ - if you want to get everyone on board, you need to find out why they are hesitant to get on board.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you are looking to make a change happen within the organisation, where there is a degree of reluctance to accept the change. I wrote a blog about this a while ago - [**here is link to it**](http://www.praefectusconsulting.co.uk/change.php) - which describes a change management model I have used in various ways for some years. Basically, to make change happen, you need to demonstrate a need for the change, create a vision of how things will be after the change, develop a plan for the change, and ensure you have sufficient resources to support the change process.

If this does not overcome the resistance - i.e. if it doesn't get the buy-in that you seek - then look at each of the components (need, vision, plan, and resources) and work out which is letting you down, fix it, and go round the loop again.

Note that the resources and the plan that I refer to is not *necessarily* the plan you have drawn up and the budget that you have already secured. What I am referring to is a budget and a plan to gain the commitment of your colleagues who need to be won over. This could be different - but only you will be able to identify whether this is the case.

Comment: @ lain9688 basically the founders are backed up me formally but side by side sometimes they are showing the same habit like the "reluctant" also and I think this manner is destructive a bit. I will read you blog but I like to ask some exact example regarding "demonstrate a need for the change". I think the commitment of my colleagues about the change is ready nevertheless the only problem is the execution. We worked out plan also and rules but they are really fresh so we have to implement in the daily routine. Tamas

Answer (score 0):

You need explain the bigger picture and make sure the goals of the project and colleagues are going in same direction.

Resistence to change comes because people don't see any value add from that change. If your negligent/reluctant colleagues can gain/learn from it they will readily work towards the project goal.

It's a matter of aligning the goals, communicating honestly and clearly and setting expectations right.

As CodeGnome commented above, it would be great if you could share what have you tried so far and what are the results?